# How would my MariaDB database be accessed by other people using JDBC?

Tags: java, mariadb

For a university project, we were taught to use JDBC to connect to a [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) database. The database was created on localhost:3306.

This is what we used:

```java
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dbname", username, password);
```

I am now doing an online group project using [GitHub](https://github.com/). How would my group partners gain access to this database if it is not on their local machine? I read somewhere about SQLdump but I couldn't seem to get it working. If I successfully did an SQLdump, could I just include the file in github and it would work for them?

Otherwise, would I need to put it on a public server?

Comment: Change `localhost:3306.` to `xxx:3306.` where xxx is a publicly accessible ip address or hostname.

Comment: Changing localhost to an ip address as you suggested causes a connection time out.

Comment: I would guess that either it is not *a publicly accessible ip address* or the port 3306 is not available.  Maybe check using canyouseeme.org

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide whether you want to share the data or the database:

### share data

This will put copies of data to your group members. Every one of you has his/her own copy in a locally installed MariaDB database, and every one of you can access it using `localhost` in the connection string.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/backup-and-restore-overview/

The sql dump file can be easily shared with others. If you find the backup/restore stuff is getting tedious and merging the data is a requirement, check for https://www.liquibase.org/, or even consider going for the shared database.

### shared database

- Ensure your MariaDB server not only binds to localhost (127.0.0.1) but also to your machine's public IP.
- open your machine's firewall to allow access to this IP. Maybe you have to look at more firewalls to be opened (e.g. your router).
- create user accounts that are allowed to connect from their respective host or from any host (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#account-names)

You can do all that from your local development machine. If you find the network or uptime requirements are not comfortable, switch to a dedicated server. This may be a cloud solution or on-premise, whatever is comfortable for you.